# How do you read a dataset in R taking n rows as 1?

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset like this:

```
11 85 1 1 2 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 75 -9. name
25 85 1 1 1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
5 1 63 -9. name
```

And I would like to read it every 3 rows, in such way that the result should be as follows:

```
11 85 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 75 -9. name
25 85 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 63 -9. name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read the data with `readLines`

```
lines <- readLines('file.txt')
```

Create a grouping variable with `grepl` and  `paste` the lines together

```
lines1 <- unname(tapply(lines, c(0, head(cumsum(grepl("name", lines)),-1)),
                          paste, collapse=' '))
cat(lines1, sep="\n")
#11 85 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 75 -9. name
#25 85 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 63 -9. name
```